# Making input command

Tags: java, command-line

I have a little problem with making a java command for program i have some code but i do not know how to continue i stuck in one place BTW the command i want to make is `/sendcash [username] [money] // how it looks like`

I have this code:

```
if (cmd.equals(AdminCommands[1])) {
        String player = scanner.next();
        int money = scanner.nextInt();
        File folder = new File(player);
        File pFile = new File(folder, player + ".txt");
        File bFile = new File(folder, money + ".txt");
        if (pFile.exists() && bFile.exists()) {
            try {
                Account pAcc = new Account(player, money);
                if(pAcc.admin != 1) {
                    try {
                        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(bFile));
                        writer.write(player);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    LabelInfo.setText("Money transfer complited ! ( " + money + " ) to ( " + pAcc.name + " )");
                } else {
                    LabelInfo.setText("You can't transfer money to an admin!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username doesn't exist!");
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** Now with this code nothing happening in the console and in the files too i dont know what to do here is the code in the class `Account`

```
public Account(String player, int cash) {
    this.username = player;
    this.money = cash;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved i actually have missed something in the constructor class `Account` and also can somebody explain me why with the brackets in `writer.write(""+cashTransfer);` are not showing the characters like `✐, 蚠, etc..` for example when i will put in [cash] field `100` its shows me the letter `d` and so on ...

Here is the whole working code...

```
if (cmd.equals(AdminCommands[1])) {
        String playerUsername = scanner.next();
        int cashTransfer = scanner.nextInt();

        File folder = new File(playerUsername);
        File pFile = new File(folder, playerUsername + ".txt");
        File bFile = new File(folder, "balance.txt");
        if (pFile.exists()) {
            try {
                Account pAcc = new Account(playerUsername, cashTransfer);
                FileWriter bWriter = new FileWriter(bFile);
                BufferedWriter writer;
                writer = new BufferedWriter(bWriter);
                writer.write(""+cashTransfer);
                pAcc.SaveInfo();
                writer.close();
                LabelInfo.setText("Money transfer complited ! ( $" + cashTransfer + " ) to ( " + pAcc.username + " )");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: Can't save balance !");
            }
        } else {
            LabelInfo.setText("Player not found !");
        }
    }
```

BTW Thank you @Salah for helping me !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by transfer the money to write the result into files, you can do it like this:

```
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pFile));
        writer.write(player);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how do i transfer the amount of money into the file if you can understand me :/

Comment: at the same way, initialize the `BufferWriter` with money file, then write the money string into it.

Comment: when you initialized `Account` object `pAcc`, you didn't set a value for admin, so i think `if(pAcc.admin != 1)v will not be true and the code will not write anything. by the way you need to writers if you want to write on both the files.

Comment: Yea i think you should do that, if its like what i have edit above.

Comment: But then tells me i need to remove and this too `writer.close();`

Comment: i didn't get what do you mean?

Comment: Okay so after some editing the code i have arrived to the solution but now i have other problem with the input in the file, when ill send the money to the file its gives me some weird characters like `✐, 蚠, etc..` what should i do to fix this ?

Comment: is it English or something else?

Comment: depends on the number i put in the [cash] field